# Titanium not recognizing its own API for android

Tags: android, appcelerator-titanium

I have a window that's part of a tab group. When I try to set the right nav button, I get the following runtime error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #Window has no method setRightNavButton`

However, the method is clearly listed in the API for `Titanium.UI.Window`. Interestingly enough, it doesn't have a problem with the `setLeftNavButton` method which is executed just before. Also, it executes perfectly running on ios, but has issues when running on android. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the code to create the window in question:

```
var queryWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
        barColor : '#1ADC2FF',
        layout : 'vertical',
        backgroundColor : '#1389d1',
        title : L('Search'),
        fullscreen : true
    });

var clearButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title : L('Clear'),
    style : Titanium.UI.iPhone.SystemButtonStyle.BORDERED,
    right : 10,
    width : 60,
    font : {
        fontSize : 14
    },
    color : '#2952CC',
    height : 30
});

....<MORE UI INITIALIZATION>....

queryWindow.setLeftNavButton(findButton);
queryWindow.setRightNavButton(clearButton); //Error thrown here

queryWindow.add(queryTable);
queryWindow.add(queryView);

return queryTab;
```

Answer (score 0):

The method setRightNavButton and setLeftNavButton is only for iOS, that's why it throw an error on Android : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-method-setRightNavButton